# java : how to remove whitespace between letters of a word in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, sed, whitespace

I have a really big text file and I am having some problems with string formatting. I have passed the whole text file into a string, but there is only one problem. There are some portions in the file with this kind of text:

```
S E N T I N E L S    A R E  I N   T H E   S K Y
```

- There are at least 2 white space characters in between the WORDS.
- There is only 1 white space character in between the LETTERS.

and I have to convert this specific portion to this format:

```
sentinels are in the sky
```

NOTE: TO SEE THE ORIGINAL TEXT FILE CLICK ON THIS LINK: http://files.seds.org/pub/software/text/weather.txt

Comment: Did you try something ? If yes post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
String data = "S E N T I N E L S    A R E  I N   T H E   S K Y";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("\\s(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\\s)\\s+", ""));
```

This regex will match and remove

- `\\s(?=[A-Z])` every space that has uppercase letter after it
- `(?<=\\s)\\s+` one or more spaces that have space before it.

If you want to convert result to lower case you can just call `toLowerCase()`.